# How can I set up forwarding domains to each have its own IP address?

Tags: domain-forwarding

For example (just an example, I don't own any of these domains):

I have a main website chocolate-dessert.com

I also own some other chocolate-related domains:

- chocolate-treat.com
- chocolate-snack.com

For SEO purposes, I want to forward the two additional domains to chocolate-dessert.com, the principle being that I can better capture keyword searches for "chocolate treat" and "chocolate snack" with those other domain names.

It's my understanding that in order for that to be effective (SEO-wise), each of the secondary domains would need to have its own IP address.

But since both of the secondary domains are registered at the same registrar (GoDaddy), they would have the same IP address as each other (according to GoDaddy).

Can anyone think of a method whereby each of the secondary domains could have a unique IP address but still forward to the primary domain?

Answer (score 2):

If you are redirecting, or forwarding, then the chocolate-treat.com won't ever get into Google. You'll only see chocolate-dessert in there. So you can't really accomplish what you're trying to do.

The better way is to create new websites on chocolate-treat.com and chocolate-snack.com and produce some great content on those domains. Great content always wins out over sneaky SEO tricks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the SEO end, but the best method to do what you are suggesting is to have a dedicated server and buy multiple IPs for it.

You can then set (within the server application) each IP to point to the same application files.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately a dedicated server would cost too much and I'm looking for a more economical solution.